# Animate setFillColor color change in custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a custom `UIView` called `CircleView` which is essentially a colored ellipse. The color property I'm using to color the ellipse is rendered using `setFillColor` on the graphics context. I was wondering if there was a way to animate the color change, because when I run through the animate / transition the color changes immediately instead of being animated.

**Example Setup**

```
let c = CircleView()
c.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
c.color = UIColor.blue
c.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.view.addSubview(c)

UIView.transition(with: c, duration: 5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    c.color = UIColor.red // Not animated
})

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
    c.color = UIColor.yellow // Not animated
}
```

**Circle View**

```
class CircleView : UIView {

    var color = UIColor.blue {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}

        context.addEllipse(in: rect)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the color change?In the View did load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in animation support for the layer's `backgroundColor`.
While the easiest way to make a circle is to make your view a square (using aspect ratio constraints, for instance) and then set the `cornerRadius` to half the width or height, I assume you want something a bit more advanced, and that is why you used a path.
My solution to this would be something like:

```
class CircleView : UIView {

var color = UIColor.blue {
    didSet {
        layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

// Setup the view, by setting a mask and setting the initial color
private func setup(){
    layer.mask = shape
    layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
}

// Change the path in case our view changes it's size
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    // add an elipse, or what ever path/shapes you want
    path.addEllipse(in: bounds)
    // Created an inverted path to use as a mask on the view's layer
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: path).reversing().cgPath
}
// this is our shape
private var shape = CAShapeLayer()
}
```

Or if you really need a simple circle, just something like:

```
class CircleView : UIView {

var color = UIColor.blue {
    didSet {
        layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup(){
    clipsToBounds = true
    layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
}
}
```

Either way, this will animate nicely:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
        self.circle.color = .red
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I prefer the first solution because I actually have lot of different shapes working the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Strange things happens!

Your code is ok, you just need to call your animation in another method and asyncronusly

As you can see, with

```
let c = CircleView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    c.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
    c.color = UIColor.blue
    c.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.view.addSubview(c)
    changeColor()
}


func changeColor(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        UIView.transition(with: self.c, duration: 5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.c.color = UIColor.red // Not animated
        })

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            self.c.color = UIColor.yellow // Not animated
        }
    }
}
```

Work as charm. 
Even if you add a button that trigger the color change, when you press the button the animation will work.

I encourage you to set this method in the definition of the CircleView

```
func changeColor(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.color = UIColor.red 
            })

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
                self.color = UIColor.yellow 
            }
    }
}
```

and call it where you want in your ViewController, simply with

```
c.changeColor()
```

Comment: Wow it's actually really strange that this works. I didn't know you could change UI in async but I guess this makes sense since it's still on the main thread. Will for sure keep this in mind thank you :)

Comment: Yep, the UI need to be changed in the main thread (well it could be changed even in other thread but you could get crashes), and you must use async because if you go through a sync way, you will block all the UI interactions